# post fix to send and receive mail to gmail using free domain and private ip

Tags: gmail, postfix

I would like to configure mail server to send and receive mail from all domain such as gmail and yahoo using postfix in my laptop.
Should I have a paid public static ip address for this purpose? or can I use my own private ip address such as 192.168.0.3 .I have already registered a free domain name.
should I create mx record or reverse DNS or A record for my domain name with my domain registrar?.I have already created A record with in my computer using BIND DNS service.
Should I also create an mx record in my computer?please help me?can i get step by step tutorial for the same?.what is the format of mx record and which IP should i use to create A record in my domain registrar?
thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If by, "send and receive" you mean you're wanting to setup an [SMTP Relay](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/345/what-is-smtp-relay) server, then yes, I believe you will need to have a static IP address. It's possibly you may even need a business class IP address. This is because due to spam over the years, most of the popular email services such as gmail, yahoo and hotmail block SMTP Relaying from known residential IP addresses. If you're familiar enough with the SMTP protocol, you easily verify whether an email server will deny relaying because of residential IP addresses by using `nslookup` and `telnet` to manually try and relay an email. There might be an easier, more graphical way, but I've always done it this way and it's the only way I know...

**Server response when trying to relay using gmail.**

> 550-5.7.1 [xx.xx.xx.xx] The IP you're using to send mail is not authorized to
>   550-5.7.1 send email directly to our servers. Please use the SMTP relay at your
>   550-5.7.1 service provider instead. Learn more at
>   550 5.7.1 http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?answer=10336 un7si7919498wjc.70 - gsmtp
>   Connection closed by foreign host.

The link in the quoted response above confirms that you will need a static IP, or possibly business class IP (this is probably ISP dependant)...

> **What can I do to fix this?**
>
> Your ISP may provide SMTP relays which will accept mail from your IP, and these servers should be authorized to send mail. Some ISPs may provide a way to get an IP that is authorized, either by upgrading to business class service or static IP service. You should reach out to your ISP to see what options are available.